# Java Regex is including new line in match

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match a regular expression to textbook definitions that I get from a website.
The definition always has the word with a new line followed by the definition. For example:

```
Zither
 Definition: An instrument of music used in Austria and Germany It has from thirty to forty wires strung across a shallow sounding board which lies horizontally on a table before the performer who uses both hands in playing on it Not to be confounded with the old lute shaped cittern or cithern
```

In my attempts to get just the word (in this case "Zither") I keep getting the newline character.

I tried both `^(\w+)\s` and `^(\S+)\s` without much luck. I thought that maybe `^(\S+)$` would work, but that doesn't seem to successfully match the word at all. I've been testing with rubular, http://rubular.com/r/LPEHCnS0ri; which seems to successfully match all my attempts the way I want, despite the fact that Java doesn't.

Here's my snippet

```
String str = ...; //Here the string is assigned a word and definition taken from the internet like given in the example above.
Pattern rgx = Pattern.compile("^(\\S+)$");
Matcher mtch = rgx.matcher(str);
if (mtch.find()) {
    String result = mtch.group();
    terms.add(new SearchTerm(result, System.nanoTime()));
}
```

This is easily solved by triming the resulting string, but that seems like it should be unnecessary if I'm already using a regular expression.

All help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `\s` matches `\n` among others.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using the Pattern.MULTILINE option

```
Pattern rgx = Pattern.compile("^(\\S+)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
```

This causes the regex to recognise line delimiters in your string, otherwise `^` and `$` just match the start and end of the string.

Although it makes no difference for this pattern, the `Matcher.group()` method returns the entire match, whereas the `Matcher.group(int)` method returns the match of the particular capture group `(...)` based on the number you specify.  Your pattern specifies one capture group which is what you want captured.  If you'd included `\s` in your Pattern as you wrote you tried, then `Matcher.group()` would have included that whitespace in its return value.

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks, I didn't realize that you had to specify multiple lines.

Answer (score 2):

With regular expressions the first group is always the complete matching string. In your case you want group 1, not group 0.

So changing `mtch.group()` to `mtch.group(1)` should do the trick:

```
 String str = ...; //Here the string is assigned a word and definition taken from the internet like given in the example above.
 Pattern rgx = Pattern.compile("^(\\w+)\s");
 Matcher mtch = rgx.matcher(str);
 if (mtch.find()) {
     String result = mtch.group(1);
     terms.add(new SearchTerm(result, System.nanoTime()));
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

A late response, but if you are not using Pattern and Matcher, you can use this alternative of `DOTALL` in your regex string

```
(?s)[Your Expression]
```

Basically `(?s)` also tells dot to match all characters, including line breaks

Detailed information: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Answer (score 1):

Just replace:

```
String result = mtch.group();
```

By:

```
String result = mtch.group(1);
```

This will limit your output to the contents of the [capturing group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) (e.g. `(\\w+)`) .

Answer (score 0):

Try the next:

```
/* The regex pattern: ^(\w+)\r?\n(.*)$ */
private static final REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile("^(\\w+)\\r?\\n(.*)$");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Zither\n Definition: An instrument of music";

    System.out.println(
        REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input).matches()
    );  // prints "true"

    System.out.println(
        REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input).replaceFirst("$1 = $2")
    );  // prints "Zither =  Definition: An instrument of music"

    System.out.println(
        REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input).replaceFirst("$1")
    );  // prints "Zither"
}
```